# Dockerfile Win 10 Firewall issues

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile for a django app:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /server
WORKDIR /server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y \
libsqlite3-dev
RUN pip install -U pip setuptools
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
WORKDIR /server/django
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "../docker-entrypoint-server"]
```

relevant docker-compose related to it:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
   build: .
   container_name: server
   environment:
     SERVER_ENV: ${SERVER_ENV}
     DB_AUTH_SOURCE: ${DB_AUTH_SOURCE}
     DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
     DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
     DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
     DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
   networks:
     - app
   ports:
     - 8081:8000
   volumes:
     - .:/server
   command: /bin/bash
   tty: true
   stdin_open: true
```

they work like a charm on linux/mac, but not on Windows 10. When the build reaches the COPY instruction, all it copies are the directory and **only** the first nested directory within it with no content attached to it.

tried to check for the shared C:\ option on docker, didnt work.
tried on powershell with admin rights and nothing.

What could be the possible causes? Why it works on two host OS and not on Win 10?

## edit 1: versions

Windows: Windows 10 Education, 1803

Linux: Ubuntu 18.03 LTS

Mac: High Sierra 10.03

Docker: latest version on all OSs

## edit 2: the solution

Turns out that unsharing and sharing, pointed out by [JDPeckham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288346/jdpeckham), revealed the problem: a firewall misconfig caused by an antivirus that was controlling these configs.

This article: https://success.docker.com/article/error-a-firewall-is-blocking-file-sharing-between-windows-and-the-containers is very helpful for troubleshooting those.

Comment: Can you fix the title please?

Comment: did you try unsharing and sharing again? if you have changed your password since you shared the folder it keeps the old password cached but never re-prompts you.

Comment: Did you try to run the commands from windows default **CMD terminal (Command Prompt)**? In my case, only the default CMD terminal (Command Prompt) worked.